# Removing events map.on("click"...) from mapbox gl?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I remove the layers with map.removeLayer("clusters"); but got this error

> evented.js:111 The layer 'clusters' does not exist in the map's style
> and cannot be queried for features.

as I have `map.on('click', 'clusters', function (e) { ...` event. So how to remove this?

Comment: I have a similar question. So I have: window.onClick = function (e) {...} map.on('click', 'driver001', onClick); and map.on('click', 'driver002', onClick); and when I try to remove these event listeners with: map.off('click', 'driver001', onClick); and map.off('click', 'driver002', onClick); if only removes the event listeners from the last layer created is there anyway to remove the event listener from both layers? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user please take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about our focused Q&A format. This appears to not be an answer, but rather a similar issue to the original question. Please do not post non-answers -- you can start a new question and reference this one. This will allow more people to see it and possibly lend assistance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First split out the click function so it can be referenced on it's own:

```
function onClick(e) {...}
```

Then register your on click with:

```
map.on('click', 'clusters', onClick);
```

Then just before you `removeLayer`, remove the event listener with

```
map.off('click', 'clusters', onClick);
```

See also https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#off.

Comment: I opened https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5145 to see if it's something GL JS should fix so that you don't need to remove the listener.

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5145 was fixed in Mapbox GL JS master so should be in the next release 0.40.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in React. I was trying something similar and come accross this thread. So in my case I wanted to remove an on click listener which would add some custom markers. Here is how I did it (for testing):

`Attributes in File`

`const map = useRef(null);`

```
map.current.on('click', (event) => addMarkerOnClick(event));
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Disabled")
  map.current.off('click', (event) => addMarkerOnClick(event));
}, 5000)
```

**The above was how I had my code initially, it WONT work.**

```
    map.current.on('click', addMarkerOnClick);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Disabled")
      map.current.off('click', addMarkerOnClick);
    }, 5000)
```

**That's the solution.**

For none React users, I suggest this:

```
// Attributes
let map = null

    map.on('click', addMarkerOnClick);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Disabled")
      map.off('click', addMarkerOnClick);
    }, 5000)
```